# Выборка значений по времени с сортировкой по дате laravel 5

Tags: laravel

Помогите выбрать из таблицы значения по дням недели. На примере:

- **10.08.2017**
- 12:40 поле1 поле2 поле3 поле4
- 13:19 поле1 поле2 поле3 поле4
- 15:51 поле1 поле2 поле3 поле4
- **09.08.2017**
- 09:27 поле1 поле2 поле3 поле4
- 11:35 поле1 поле2 поле3 поле4
- 17:28 поле1 поле2 поле3 поле4
- **08.08.2017**
- 07:59 поле1 поле2 поле3 поле4
- 14:47 поле1 поле2 поле3 поле4
- 18:08 поле1 поле2 поле3 поле4

и т.д.

Помогите поправить запрос или предложите свой вариант:
$info = $this->db->table('table')->select('date', 'поле1', 'поле2', 'поле3', 'поле4')->where('hash', $hash)->groupBy('date')->orderBy('date', 'DESC')->get()->toArray();

В Twig'e принимаю значения:

1. {% for inf in info %}
2. {% if inf.date|date("d.m.Y") != data %}
3. {{inf.date|date("d.m.Y")}}
4. {% endif %}
5. {% if inf.date|date("d.m.Y") == data %}
6. {{inf.date|date("G:i")}}
7. {% endif %}
8. {% set data = inf.date|date("d.m.Y") %}
9. {% endfor %}

Всё вроде работает, но может кто-то посоветует с оптимизацией!
Спасибо всем за внимание!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Какая версия Laravel? 5.3?

```
$tr = $this->db->table('table')->select('date', 'поле1', 'поле2', 'поле3', 'поле4')->where('hash', $hash)->orderBy('date', 'DESC')->get()

$info = $tr->groupBy(function($item){return date('d.m.Y', $item->date);})->toArray();
```